# Combining the state and observable patterns in Rust

Tags: oop, rust, observer-pattern, state-pattern

I've been interested in working with Rust for a while and wanted to recreate one of my school projects in it. This project involves creating an Order which goes through multiple stages much like [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html) post from the rust docs.

However, a problem arose when trying to implement the observer pattern on the State of this Order. I want the ability to subscribe to this State and to do this the State should contain a Vector of Observers.

```rust
struct Order {
    order_state: Box<dyn State>,
}

impl Order {
    pub fn new() -> Order {
        return Order {
            order_state: Box::new(Created {}),
        };
    }

    pub fn print_state(&self) {
        self.order_state.print_state();
    }

    pub fn complete(&mut self) {
        self.order_state = Box::new(Completed {})
    }
}

trait State {
    fn print_state(&self);
}

struct Created {}

impl State for Created {
    /*
    This variable would specify a constraint on the state
    that the state must have a list of observers that have certain
    functionality.

    let observers: Vec<Observer>;

    fn send_update(&str) {
        observers.iter().foreach(|observer| observer.receiveMessage(&str))
    }
    */

    fn print_state(&self) {
        println!("I have been created!")
    }
}

struct Completed {}

impl State for Completed {
    fn print_state(&self) {
        println!("I have been completed!")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a: Order = Order::new();
    a.print_state();

    a.complete();
    // a.send_update("Status changed!")
    a.print_state();
}
```

The thing is, traits cannot hold variables such as the Vec I was going to use. In C# (which I origionally build this in) we could overcome this by having an abstract class. My question now is, how do I combine these patterns in Rust?

I am aware that a proposal for variables in traits exists [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1546) but seeing as it was suggested back in 2016, I am not holding out hope.

Comment: Why not just add the field to every struct? Also, in Rust when we have a closed list of types, we usually use an enum and not a trait object.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Adding the field to every struct is of course possible but causes a lot of overhead and doesn't guarantee that every struct has that field. As for the reason I used structs instead of an enum, that is because I followed the example provided by the rust docs and made the most sense to me as I'm yet unfiimilair with how Rust enums exactly work.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with enums, it is important. Anyway, if _all_ states contain a list of observers, then it should probably the responsibility of `Order` to manage it.

Comment: I've thought about making the observers part of `Order` I don't think that is the correct course of action as the `send_update` method needs access to it and doing so should be the responsibility of the state itself. Also, this would eliminate the possibility of a default implementation which is valuable when a lot of states get added.

Comment: Quite the opposite: instead of duplicating the code for each state to notify the observers, you only update the state in `send_update()` and only in `Order::state_update()` you call `send_update()` of the state then notify the observers. Why would this eliminate the possiblity of a default implementation?

Comment: Some [observer pattern advice](https://cppfaq.rs/codebase.html) from google's cppfaq.rs

Comment: Because the `send_update()` method might have a different implementation for any given state. So I'd like to define it inside the trait.